# How to use jQuery.autocomplete on a hidden input field (type="text")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to use the autocomplete from jQuery on an text field inside a hidden div. It doesn't seem to work, though the input field gains the ui-autocomplete-input class. It's like no event is bound to my input.

Just to be clear, the code looks like this:

```
<a href="#overlay" class="open-the-overlay-that-has-the-id-like-this-href-attribute">OPEN</a>

<div id="overlay" style="display:none">
    <form action="/action" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="my-unique-id" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#my-unique-id").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2
    });

});
</script>
```

After this, the #my-unique-id gains the ui-autocomplete-input class but has no events bound.
Any ideas?

Here is the server side script, but it's nothing wrong with it, because on another field it works fine:

(CakePHP)

```
function getCity() {

    $this->layout = FALSE;
    $this->autoRender = FALSE;
    Configure::write("debug",0);

    if(isset($_GET["term"]) && !empty($_GET["term"])) {
        AppModel::unbind($this->City);
        preg_match_all("/(\w+)/",urldecode($_GET["term"]), $term);
        $or = array();
        foreach ($term[0] as $t) {
            if(strtolower($t) != "jud")
            $or[] = "City.name LIKE '%$t%'"; // OR City.county LIKE '%$t%'
        }
        $or = implode(" OR ", $or);
        $cities = $this->City->find("all", array("limit"=>30, "fields"=>array("City.id", "City.name", "City.county"),"conditions"=>array($or)));
        $returnArray = array();
        $k = 0;
        foreach($cities as $c) {
            $returnArray[$k]['id'] = $c["City"]["id"];
            $returnArray[$k]['label'] = $c["City"]["name"].", jud. ".$c["City"]["county"];
            $returnArray[$k]['value'] = $c["City"]["name"].", jud. ".$c["City"]["county"];
            $k++;
        }
        return json_encode($returnArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, what could be wrong is your server side script which is not returning data and so it looks like nothing is happening. Could you please post your server side script?

You could also try with a local datasource:

```
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];

 $("#my-unique-id").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags ,
        minLength: 2
    });
```

Comment: The server side works fine. Can't use local data source because I have about 14000 entries in the database. So it's not an option!

Comment: @Lucian - I think Nicola means for you to use local datasource to test the autocomplete functionality...

Comment: @Lucian from your example it's not clear where the user inputs the text that should be "autocompleted"

Comment: Could you be more specific @NicolaPeluchetti ?

Comment: @Lucian - autocomplete works when someone types text into input. When your input is hidden (because its in hidden div) - then nobody can actually write text there? Or are you inserting text into that input by code somewhere? Then you need to trigger that change on keyup event with your code.

Comment: that form opens inside an overlay. When I click OPEN, i can see the form.